# How do I launch a dialog to open a program from another program?

Tags: bittorrent, magnet-uri

When you click on a magnet link in a modern web browser a  dialog will open letting you select your torrent client of choice (usually the default) to open the magnet link.

But say I have a program I wrote that displays magnet links within it. What do I have to do to present a similar dialog to open the user's default torrent client after clicking on the magnet link in my program?

Comment: that largely depends on your operating system and possibly the UI framework used